# Сравнение DateTime через LINQ запрос

Tags: c#, linq

Нужно перебрать коллекцию, и вытащить элемент, дата которого равна заданной.
Пишу LINQ запрос:

```
 manager.VM = DB.FirstOrDefault(x => (x.LaunchTime.CompareTo(chosenvmlauchtime)==0));
```

Не работает.
Пробую последовательно:

```
 manager.VM = DB.FirstOrDefault(x => (x.LaunchTime==chosenvmlauchtime);
 manager.VM = DB.FirstOrDefault(x =>(x.LaunchTime.Equals(chosenvmlauchtime));
 manager.VM = DB.FirstOrDefault(x =>(Object.Equals(x.LaunchTime, chosenvmlauchtime));
```

Не работает.
При этом такой монстр:

```
manager.VM = DB.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LaunchTime.Day==chosenvmlauchtime.Day&&x.LaunchTime.Hour==chosenvmlauchtime.Hour&&x.LaunchTime.Minute==chosenvmlauchtime.Minute&&x.LaunchTime.Second==chosenvmlauchtime.Second);
```

- работает.

По тому, что нагуглил, должны работать и первые три метода. Но не работают, на выходе `null`
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы из БД данные тащите?

Comment: Нет, из ViewModel. А во ViewModel они вытягиваются из БД в конечном итоге. У меня как получается,  chosenvmlauchtime приходит из представления, куда оно попадает тоже из ViewModel. По сути дела одна и та же переменная

Comment: А сравнивать вам что нужно: часы, минуты, секунды или достаточно что бы совпадали только  даты?

Comment: Полностью, до миллисекунд. Я не понимаю, почему не работают стандартные методы.

Comment: Но ваш "монстр" сравнивает до секунд, или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: Пока да, для отладочных целей этого достаточно. Дописать миллисекунды не проблема.

Comment: @foxhound Дописать можете? Я подозреваю, что даты SQL имеют фракцию в них, которая не сохраняется в представлении

Comment: @user270576 Вы правы, при добавлении месяца, года и миллисекунд, и это перестало работать. Сейчас буду последовательно убирать добавленное, чтобы понять в чем загвоздка

Comment: @foxhound - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/688612/241961

Comment: Дело в миллисекундах. При их удалении - все работает.

Answer (score 7):

Будьте внимательны при сравнении DateTimes, сгенерированных в C#. Структура DateTime в C# имеет более высокую точность, чем тип datetime1 в SQL.

Поэтому, если вы создаете DateTime в C# (скажем, из DateTime.Now), сохраните его в базе данных и верните обратно, это, скорее всего, будет отличаться.

```
2017.07.07 12:28:23.6115968
2017.07.07 12:28:23.6100000
```

Answer (score 3):

Когда происходит сравнение двух значений `DateTime` для того что бы мы получили `true` **два объекта должны быть полностью равны вплоть до** `DateTime.Ticks`, которые представляют число тактов, представляющих дату и время данного экземпляра.

Один такт соответствует 100 наносекундам или одной десятимиллионной секунде. Существует 10 000 тактов в миллисекунде или 10 миллионов тактов в секунде.

Для того что бы понять насколько это быстро, можно провести следующий эксперимент. Создайте последовательно две переменные `DateTime` и посмотрите значение `Ticks`. Несмотря на то, что переменные создаются одна за другой количество тактов у них будет разным.

```
var ticks1 = DateTime.Now.Ticks; // 636350607119477684
var ticks2 = DateTime.Now.Ticks; // 636350607212468695
```

Answer (score 0):

Итак, вроде как разобрался. Спасибо ответившим, особенно user270576, который натолкнул меня на правильный путь.
Проект сделан на EntityFramework code-first. Базу тоже генерил EF. По умолчанию, он ставит тип данных datetime, и в результате, при преобразовании в тип `DateTime` C# теряется часть данных.   Проблема была решена принудительной сменой типа данных в БД на `datetime2`. После чего заработали и  ручной метод с миллисекундами, и стандартные методы. Принудительную смену типа провел через fluentAPI добавлением в метод файла- наследника `DBContext`. Как-то можно через атрибуты непосредственно в модели, но у меня не получилось.

код метода в файле контекста:

```
  protected override void  OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelbuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelbuilder);
        modelbuilder.Entity<SiteInfo>().
           Property(p => p.LaunchTime)
           .HasColumnType("datetime2")
           .HasPrecision(0)
           .IsRequired();

    }
```

ЗЫ: для коллег-начинающих: не забудьте после изменений выполнить в Консоли диспетчера пакетов команды `Add-Migration [name]` и `Upgrade-Database -Verbose` для обновления БД.